# Chaining Applicatives

Tags: haskell

I wrote this code to append `Maybe`'s:

```
ghci> (:) <$> Just 5 <*> ((:) <$> Just 100 <*> Just [])
Just [5,100]
```

Similarly:

```
ghci> (:) <$> Just 5 <*> ( (:) <$> Just 10 <*> ((:) <$> Just 100 <*> Just []) )
Just [5,10,100]
```

Is this code idiomatic? Perhaps there's a more concise way to append a bunch of `Maybe`'s together?

Comment: What is the actual code this situation risen? Why not just write `Just [5,10,100]`?

Comment: Just curious how to do it with `<*>`. No real purpose other than curiosity.

Comment: W.r.t. difference between `sequence` and `concatMap maybeToList`: `sequence [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2]` is `Nothing`; whereas `concatMap maybeToList [Just 1, Nothing, Just 2]` is `[1, 2]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, while the code surely works, it does look ugly. I would suggest something like this:

```
sequence [Just 5, Just 10, Just 100]
```

or, if you really want to use `Applicative`s instead of `Monad`s,

```
sequenceA [Just 5, Just 10, Just 100]
```

from `Data.Traversable`.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to use neither `Monad` nor `Applicative` you can just use `concatMap maybeToList` from `Data.Maybe`.

Comment: Minor point: It should be `concatMap maybeToList` instead of `concatMap . maybeToList`.